# What are the most popular blunders in the opening stage?

Tags: opening, statistics, blunder

According to the data base at lichess, after 1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e5 3. dxe5 Ng4 4. Bf4 Nc6 5. Nf3 Bb4+ 6. Nbd2 Qe7 7. a3 Ngxe5, 8. axb4?? has been played 27,409 times (including played by a player with a rating 2300+), and it is in fact the second most popular move in this position. Black wins 99% of the game after 8. axb4.

```
[fen "r1b1k2r/ppppqppp/2n5/4n3/1bP2B2/P4N2/1P1NPPPP/R2QKB1R w KQkq - 0 8"]
```

Another example: after 1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 dxe4 4. Nxe4 Nd7 5. Qe2, 5... Ngf6?? has been played 16,366 times (including played by a player with a rating 2600+) and white wins 98% of the games after 5... Ngf6??.

```
 [fen "r1bqkbnr/pp1npppp/2p5/8/3PN3/8/PPP1QPPP/R1B1KBNR b KQkq - 2 5"]
```

Statistically speaking, what are the most popular opening blunders?

Comment: "white wins 98% of the games after 5... Ngf6??" I'm struggling to work out what happens in the 2%. It's a bit early for a flag fall. Maybe White's phone goes off before they can play  Nd6#?

Comment: what is the source of the results. is it from a mega database or a lichess games database

Comment: Another evergreen is 1.e4 d5 2.exd5 Qxd5 3.d4 Nc6 4.Nf3 Bg4 5.Be2 Bxf3 6.Bxf3 Qxd4. Had (almost) the same on my board in 1975. Gelenczei's "Opening Traps" book surely will contain more beloved blunders.

Comment: @BrianTowers, not everyone chooses the move Nd6#. Nxf6+, Nf3 and nine other moves have been played.

Comment: @cmgchess I believe it is lichess games database.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann, interestingly, 6... Qxd4 is actually the most popular move in this position! No wonder people say "popularity does not mean quality". Also after 6... Qxd4, 5,757 games continued with 7. Qxd4 and 2052 games with 7. O-O.

Comment: 4.e3 in albin counter gambit

Answer (score 3):

There is scholars mate 1. e4 e5 2. Bc4 Nc6 3. Qh5 Nf6 4. Qxf7#
fallen for by 600,000 people
There is the ICBM gambit
1.e4 d5 2. Nf3 dxe4 3. Ng5 Nf6 4. d3 exd3 5. Bxd3 h6 6. Nxf7 Kxf7 7. Bg6+ Kxg6 8. Qxd8
played by 250,000 people and
1.d4 e5 2. dxe5 Bc5 3. Nf3 d6 4. exd6 Ne7 5. dxe7 Bxf2+ 6. Kxf2 Qxd1
blundered by 375,000
i hope that helps

Comment: Plz elobprate with % of GM doing this blunder